# Unique combination of attribute and element via XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

This is from my XSD as it stands now:

```
<xs:element name="Pickers">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="Picker" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:unique name="unique-prefix">
    <xs:selector xpath="st:Picker"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@prefix"/>
  </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

It makes the Picker attribute `prefix` unique e.g. `<Picker prefix="this is unique">`

I would like to modify the XPath so that what is unique is the combination of prefix and the content of the `<Picker>` element e.g. `<Picker>content</Picker>`

So, this is what I mean... `prefix+content` should be unique.

Is this possible? How could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xs:unique` can take multiple `xs:field` children:

```
<xs:unique name="unique-prefix">
    <xs:selector xpath="st:Picker"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@prefix"/>
    <xs:field xpath="."/>
</xs:unique>
```